# RabbitMQ Exception: operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found in server side

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

I define two queue 'request.queue' and 'result.queue' , my web UI produce message in the 'request.queue' and then my python app consume it from the 'request.queue' and start processing and then push result into the 'result.queue' and finally result from 'result.queue' show to user like [this link](https://bernhardwenzel.com/articles/tutorial-build-a-message-driven-microservice-application/#fn:repo). It works in my labtop with ubuntu 20.4 very well but when i put my all code into the server with ubuntu 20.4 os, it dose not work and create only 'request.queue' and then throw an exception :(  "operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: no queue 'result.queue' in vhost '/'"
and another log:
SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'result.queue' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)

RabbitMq version in the serve is 3.8.8 and the version of Erlang is 23.0.3.

Anyone can help me why my code on server throw an exception?

My java code with spring boot for declare queues is here:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestConfiguration extends RabbitMqConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.queue}")
    String queueName;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.exchange}")
    String exchange;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.routingkey}")
    String routingkey;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, true);
   }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingkey);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}


#And for consumer:

@Configuration
public class ResultConsumerConfiguration extends RabbitMqConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.resultQueue}")
    String resultQueueName;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.resultExchange}")
    String exchange;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.resultRoutingkey}")
    String routingkey;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(resultQueueName, true);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingkey);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        converter.setClassMapper(classMapper());
        return converter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DefaultClassMapper classMapper() {
        DefaultClassMapper typeMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        typeMapper.setDefaultType(ResultMessageGeneral.class);

        return typeMapper;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setRoutingKey(this.resultQueueName);
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.setQueueNames(this.resultQueueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter());

        return container;
    }
    
    
     @Bean
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(rabbitMqListener, jsonMessageConverter());
        }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because 'result.queue' doesn't exist.

from your code, you just declare one queue, should be 'request.queue'

you need declare the 'result.queue' also

hope this help you